# What scriptures describe Hiranyaksha mining the Earth?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, history, avatars, varaha

Most people only know the story of the demon Hiranyaksha putting the Earth in the Garbhodska ocean, after which Vishnu’s incarnation Varaha the boar killed Hiranyaksha and rescued the Earth.  But page 41 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=SYJXBtcSRZ8C&lpg=PA41&dq=%E2%80%9Cto%20obtain%20this%20gold%20he%20mined%20the%20earth%E2%80%9D&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q&f=false) tells a different story:

> Hiranyaksha was the first and greatest demon that ever walked this earth. His body was so big and strong that it blocked the view in all directions just like a mountain. The crest of his crown seemed to kiss the sky and cover the sun. When he walked the earth shook at his every step. Even the demigods hid themselves from him. Fearing death at the hands of no one, he wandered the earth searching for a suitable opponent to fight. He wore golden anklets, a golden girdle, golden bracelets on his arms, golden armour and a crown of gold. **To obtain this gold he mined the earth. He considered the earth as his property to do with as he wished, and so he mined her deeper and deeper – so deep that she lost her inner balance and fell from her position in space.** Plunging to the depths she came to rest in the primeval waters which lie at the very bottom of the universe. There she lay, lost and helpless in the darkness.

Srila Prabhupada also alludes to this story in [this section](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/7/1/) of his commentary on the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> Only under certain conditions do the planets float as weightless balls in the air, and as soon as these conditions are disturbed, the planets may fall down in the Garbhodaka Ocean, which covers half the universe. The other half is the spherical dome within which the innumerable planetary systems exist. The floating of the planets in the weightless air is due to the inner constitution of the globes, and the modernized drilling of the earth to exploit oil from within is a sort of disturbance by the modern demons and can result in a greatly harmful reaction to the floating condition of the earth. **A similar disturbance was created formerly by the demons headed by Hiraṇyākṣa (the great exploiter of the gold rush)**, and the earth was detached from its weightless condition and fell down into the Garbhodaka Ocean.

So my question is, what scriptures describe Hiranyaksha disturbing the Earth by extracting gold from it?

Or is it just folklore?